# Chrome Extension access Files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my chrome extension to access a sqllite file which is part of the extension. I looked up the chrome.storeage api, but it doesnt really help me! And my JavaScript knowledge isnt enough to access a file and read its content.

Also is it possible to start my extension when a specific file type is loaded?

Comment: One question per post, please.  How would you access the file if it weren't a chrome extension?

Comment: _"I want my chrome extension to access a sqllite file which is part of the extension"_ You can do that, but only read-only.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read a json file named env.json in the root of the extension directory.

1. Add the following configuration to the manifest.json. You need to add your sqlite file in this configuration.

```
 "web_accessible_resources": [
  "*.json"
 ],
```

2. I defined a function to load json file. You need to tweak the response data, cause the sqlite file is a binary data file instead of a text file.

```
// the path is relative to the extension directory
let loadData = async path => {
  let url = chrome.runtime.getURL(path);
  let resp = await fetch(url)
  let json = resp.json()

  return json
}
```

3. Usage example

```
// Use the above function to load extension file
let conf = await loadData('env.json')
```